# Word macro to remove formatting behaves differently when implemented as VB Script

Tags: vba, ms-word

There is an existing macro used to remove highlight formatting from a document:

```
Sub RemoveShading()
Selection.Font.Shading.Texture = wdTextureNone
Selection.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorWhite
Selection.Shading.ForegroundPatternColor = wdColorWhite
End Sub
```

This has been working fine; when I select all text and run the macro with changes tracked in the document, I see the document updated with changes like:

> Formatted: Pattern Clear

and

> Formatted: Pattern: Solid (100%) (White)

in the locations where the highlighting previously existed in the document.

However, now, for reasons, I need to implement this as a VB Script (VBS). When I apply what I understand to be the exact same code:

```
    ' Open the current file
    Set WordDoc = Word.Documents.Open(objFile.path)
    
    ' select and de-highlight the whole document
    Word.Selection.WholeStory
    Set WordText = Word.Selection
    WordText.Font.Shading.Texture = wdTextureNone
    WordText.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorWhite
    WordText.Shading.ForegroundPatternColor = wdColorWhite

    ' save in a new file to preserve original
    newPath = objFSO.BuildPath(objFolder.path, objFSO.GetBaseName(objFile.path)&"_done.docx")
    WordDoc.SaveAs(newPath)
    WordDoc.Close
```

Instead, the entire document has tracked changes like:

> Formatted: Font: Default (Arial)
> Formatted: Font: Not Bold
> Formatted: Font: (Default) Arial, 11pt
> Formatted: Font: Not Bold,
> Not Italic

In addition, the entire document now has a white background on all the text, which I only noticed because I have a dark theme on office on my machine (but not the one on which I originally ran the macro). However when I run that same macro on my machine, the background remains blank instead of turning white.

What am I doing wrong here? How could the same code do such different things to the same document?

The only thing I can think of is that I'm doing the selection wrong, as this is of course not present in the original macro, but that doesn't really make any sense to me.

Many thanks!

Comment: Both macros change the background color of selected text to white. Using the selection object is often a mistake. Working from recorded macros is not the best. This does not clear highlighting but does clear shading, or at least change it to white.---- Is what you want to do to remove shading where it has been applied? Do you want to also remove highlighting? (Highlighting is different from shading.) How about in headers/footers and textboxes?

Comment: It's probably because VBScript does not recognise the constant values wdTextureNone etc. - you should replace them by the values you can find, e.g. by looking them up in the Object Browser in the VB Editor.

Comment: thanks for the comments, this is my first vba/vbs task ever, so I'm not really sure what I'm doing. You say both scripts change the background, and that makes sense based on what the code says, but only the vbs script actually makes the background white; the macro doesn't. if vbs doesn't recognize those values, why would it turn them white? I'm confused how the same code could have such different results, like font changes???

Comment: Yes, it can be confusing. When you code using VBA in Word, VBA recognizes a whole lot of names of constant values that are defined in the Word object model. So for example, wdColorWhite is a constant whose value is 16777215. 

But VBScript doesn't know about those values. As far as it is concerned, instead of saying "= wdColorWhite", you might as well have said "= blah". Because your code did not assign a value to "blah", VBScript thinks the value is 0. So in VBA, wdColorWhite is 16777215, but in VBScript it is 0. And in fact, the wdColor constant whose value is 0 is wdColorBlack...

Comment: ...So in effect, your VBScript code is saying <the color you are trying to set > = wdColorBlack. i.e. it is not what you intended. You may be able to use "= 16777215" instead , or do something like Dim wbColorWhite , then wbColorWhite = 16777215, but I haven't actually checked that that works for sure.

Comment: thanks again, what you are saying would make sense if I was seeing the colors change to random stuff or if I got some kind of error... but even if I remove everything except setting WordText.Font.Shading.Texture = 0 which should be correct, the change tracking still shows changes like fonts, bolds, etc. If the only thing attempted to change was the shading, why would it report changes to any other property? If this is a rabbit hole, ultimately what I need to achieve is a way to apply this macro to documents in a folder without opening them and adding macro to them one by one, can this be done?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your comment because you didn't reference my name. If you are still working on this one, if things changed because of the comments you received, it would be very helpful if you could modify your question to reflect those changes. We are not seeing what you are seeing!